# Why is any row of reduced matrix a linear combination of the rows of the first?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I study the linear algebra.

There is the following corollary from Linear Combination Lemma in the book:

> Where one matrix reduces to another, each row of the second is a
>   linear combination of the rows of the first.

I really can't understand what it does mean.

If we have two reducible matrices A -> B then a[i] row must be reduced to  b[i], however why is b[i] a linear combination of **all** rows of A? Just because any factor of A is null vector at this case?

Please give me any example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The operations of row reduction are the addition (or subtraction) of the row vectors with the other row vectors... So any resultant vector must be a combination of the vectors from the original matrix.

I think you have a problem with the word "all."

If I have row vectors $v_1, v_2, v_3, v_4,$
$v = v_1 + 2v_2 - 3v_3 + 0v_4$ is a linear combination of the 4 vectors even if the weight of $v_4$ happens to be $0.$